# Ruby pack - TypeError: can't convert String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jruby

I am getting `TypeError: can't convert String into Integer`, I found duplicate answer too, but I am facing this error for 'pack'.

Other confusion is, it is working fine with `ruby 1.8.7`, not with `ruby 1.9.3`, here is the code, I am using `jruby1.7.2`

```
irb(main):003:0> length=nil
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> token_string ||= ["A".."Z","a".."z","0".."9"].collect { |r| r.to_a }.join + %q(!$:*)
=> "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!$:*"
irb(main):005:0> token =  (0..(length ? length : 60)).collect { token_string[rand( token_string.size)]}.pack("c*")
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
    from (irb):5:in `pack'
    from (irb):5
    from /home/appandya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'
irb(main):006:0>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, I don't know why previously was -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string[x]` in `Ruby 1.8` gives you a `Fixnum` (the character code) and in `1.9` it gives you a `single character string`.

Array#pack turns an array into a binary sequence.  The "c*" template to pack converts an array of Ruby integers into a stream of 8-bit signed words.

Here are the solutions, those comes from the Google Groups

**1.**

Background

```
>> %w(a b c).pack('*c')
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
        from (irb):1:in `pack'
        from (irb):1
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
>> [1, 2, 3].pack('*c')
=> "\x01"
>> %w(a b c).map(&:ord).pack('*c')
=> "a"
```

Solution

```
irb(main):001:0> length=nil
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> token_string ||= ["A".."Z","a".."z","0".."9"].collect { |r| r.to_a }.join + %q(!$:*)
=> "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!$:*"
irb(main):003:0> (0..(length ? length : 60)).collect { token_string[rand( token_string.size)]}.map(&:ord).pack("c*")
=> "rd!:!LcxU3ON57*t2s520v*zvvdflSNAgU6uq14SiD00VUDlm9:4:tJz5Ri5o"
irb(main):004:0>
```

**2.**

The return type of `String's []` function was `Fixnum` in `1.8` but is `String` in `1.9`:

```
>JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9 ruby -e "puts 'a'[0].class"
String

>JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8 ruby -e "puts 'a'[0].class"
Fixnum
```

`JRuby 1.7.x` defaults to acting like `Ruby 1.9.3`. You need to set `JRUBY_OPTS`.

**3.**

try `join` instead of `pack`

```
irb(main):004:0> length=nil
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> token_string ||= ["A".."Z","a".."z","0".."9"].collect { |r| r.to_a }.join + %q(!$:*)
=> "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!$:*"
irb(main):006:0> token =  (0..(length ? length : 60)).collect { token_string[rand( token_string.size)]}.join("c*")
=> "Fc*Dc*1c*6c*ac*Kc*Tc*Qc*Hc*jc*Ec*Kc*kc*zc*sc*3c*ic*hc*kc*wc**c*Wc*$c*Kc*Ic*Uc*Cc*bc*Pc*1c*!c*mc*Bc*lc*dc*ic*Dc*sc*Ac*Bc*nc*Kc*mc*Lc*oc*Zc*Xc*jc*6c*2c*Uc*ec*Yc*Dc*vc*Ic*Uc*5c*Zc*3c*o"
irb(main):007:0>
```

**4.**

if you're just trying to make a string of random characters that are 8-bit clean you may want to look at `Random#bytes` and something like `Base64.encode64`.

**5.**

**active_support/secure_random** also has a nice API for these things

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at: [Array Method Pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack), essentially the `.pack("c")` expects the elements of the array to be integers. You could try `.pack("a*")`

Comment: I am a apologies for the silly question, why .pack("a*")? why not .pack("b*") or .pack("a*")? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Use `token =  (0..(length ? length : 60)).collect { token_string[rand( token_string.size)]}.pack("a"*61)`

You get the same result. I am using 61 because, going from 0..60 has 61 elements.

Comment: pack("a"*61) is working fine, but not pack("c"*61), can you please explain on this?

Comment: As fmendez pointed out in the answer above, .pack("c") requires the array elements to be **integer**. In your case, they are all **string**. Thus the error.